# How to deploy a contract from another contract constructor?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, testing

I have the following `Interaction` contract which should deploy a new `DataStorage` contract in the constructor, but when I run my test `dataStorage` is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```
contract Interaction is Owned {
  DataStorage dataStorage;

  function Interaction() public {
    dataStorage = new DataStorage();
  }
}
```

The test (`contract.dataStorage` is undefined)

```
it('should deploy an initial DataStorage contract', async () => {
  const contract = await create();
  const dataStorage = await contract.dataStorage.call();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When defining the `dataStorage` type in my contract I forgot to set it to public. Needs to be updated to:

`DataStorage public dataStorage;`